# SQL server version 10 is not supported Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, databasepublishingwizard

Does anybody know where I can find the SQL Database Publishing Wizard for SQL Server 2008?
When I try and run version 1.1 it says that SQL server version 10 is not supported. I found a [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440724.aspx) that states there is a SQL Database publishing Wizard for SQL Server 2008 in Visual studio 2008 but I have no idea where to find it.

We are using SQL Database publishing wizard from the command line to copy the state of a database.

---Answer----

It Turns out I needed to install SP3 for Sql server 2005 to fix the "SQL Server version 10 is not supported error".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It Turns out I needed to install SP3 for Sql server 2005 to fix the "SQL Server version 10 is not supported error".

Answer (score 1):

If the database has been added to a Visual Studio 2008 solution you should see it via a right-click as "Publish To Provider"